# How Can i import Code ckeditor in my laravel app?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, forum

I am making a discussion forum application in Laravel . Here I want to use Ckeditor in comment sections. When somebody comments, then the code should show like here in stackoverflow.

```php
@if(Auth::check()!=null)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel panel-body">
                <form action="/comment" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Reply</label>
                        <textarea name="body" class="form-control" style="size: 200px"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="com" id="com"  class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-right">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Please give me very simple steps to use ckeditor. My master file is layout.app and this file is comment.blade.php. Please guide me where I should enter what files and scripts files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel CKEditor Package;

How to install:
Set up package

```
composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
```

Add ServiceProvider

Edit `config/app.php`, add the following file to `Application Service Providers` section.

```
Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Publish the resources

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

Usage
Default way (initiate by name or id) :

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
</script>
```

Or if you want to initiate by jQuery selector :

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('textarea').ckeditor();
    // $('.textarea').ckeditor(); // if class is prefered.
</script>
```

[github link for more](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor)

Example:

```
@if(Auth::check()!=null)
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel panel-body">
            <form action="/comment" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Reply</label>
                    <textarea id="editor1" name="body" class="form-control" style="size: 200px"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="com" id="com"  class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-right">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif

<script>

    $('.editor1').ckeditor(); // if class is prefered.
</script>
```

Comment: where have to paste <script> files ? in layout file or this comment blade ?

Comment: I added example for you please check

Comment: didnt get u where to add these all scripts

Comment: the bottom of after my answer you can use.   
or add this to your blade in <script> tags:          $('.textarea').ckeditor();

Comment: did you do everything?

Comment: bro its working for me . But how can i show code section like stackshows

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="{{asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')}}"></script>

@section('script')

    <script>

        $('textarea').ckeditor();
    </script>

    @endsection
```

and i have provided editor id