# UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor not working in laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

First run this command in command line.
composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor

Add in service provider 
Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,

run this command
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor

add this code in my blade file js section

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
</script>
```

there is no error but textarea show normal as like before

Comment: Try JQuery selector <script> $('textarea').ckeditor(); </script>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935623/how-can-i-import-code-ckeditor-in-my-laravel-app?rq=1

Comment: its not working

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no error. and i check it get the file of ckeditor.js

Comment: /public/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js is this the path?

Comment: and <textarea id="article-ckeditor"></textarea>

Comment: my path is okay. check it from view page source. textarea id is okay. but still not working

Comment: Strange, can you share your blade code?

Comment: @section('js')
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}">
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('body-field');
</script>
@endsection

this js section.


<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea id="body-field" class="form-control form-urcv" name="body"> </textarea>
                </div>


this is my input field

Comment: You did not close script tag after this - "<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js">"

Answer (score 1):

try to use the 'asset' method to access your ckeditor.js script from the vendor folder
try it like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more?

Comment: try change this <script src="127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"> to this <script src="{{ asset('/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
            <script>

Comment: i use asset() helper method. You can read more on asset() helper method on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset